# Setting a specific zoom and maxZoom on a layer only if there are blank tiles on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a tile layer (using OpenTopoMap) and have set a default zoom level of `13`. But some tiles in certain areas are not rendered at that zoom level, thus, they show up as blank/empty tiles. If I set the zoom level lower, the OpenTopoMap tiles for that area are displayed.

For areas having blank tiles, I want to set the zoom level to `12` (instead of `13`) so that the tiles are rendered at a lower zoom level. I tried setting/readjusting the `maxZoom` and/or `maxNativeZoom` but they obviously set the `maxZoom` regardless of whether there are blank tiles or not.

How can I set the `zoom` level and `maxZoom` level of this layer to `12` only if there are blank tiles on the map?

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [6.8387, 121.5549],
  zoom: 13,
  maxZoom: 14,
  minZoom: 12,
  zoomDelta: 1,
  dragging: !1,
  scrollWheelZoom: !1
});

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  maxZoom: 14,
  maxNativeZoom: 14,
  attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me… In any case, you would probably be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705754/mapbox-js-fallback-tile-image-from-lower-zoom-level-when-missing-in-requested/44497256#44497256

Comment: It's a good workaround. Although I would prefer to simply lower the zoom level by 1 if a tile is missing at the default zoom level. If there is a missing tile, then set the zoom 1 level lower than the default. If it still does have a missing tile, lower by 1 level again until all tiles within the area are displayed.

Comment: While you can certainly implement it the way you describe, this sounds like strange UI behaviour to me: you need to wait to receive some 404 errors to realize you miss some tiles, at which point you would forcibly change the view the user is currently navigating within. Whereas the missing tile may be just a portion of the viewport, preventing the user from seeing more details of the good tiles.

Comment: You're right. The plugin solution is indeed what I need. Thanks. The only thing I noticed when using the plugin is that the scaled up tiles are loaded again when switching to another layer and then back. Can these tiles be cached?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? If you are referring to the delay it takes to re-display the scaled up tiles, it is due to the fact that the browser tries again to load the previously missing tile. Once it gets the 404 error again, it displays the replacing scaled up tile from cache. You could improve the plugin behaviour by "remembering" the tiles that previously returned a 404 error, but you may end up with big memory, and you prevent getting a tile that was just temporarily unavailable.